# Control order of languages outside of the Content Editor

Tags: multilingual

Since [Sitecore 8.1 Update 2](http://sitecore-masters.com/en/sorting-languages-in-content-editor/), one has been able to set the display order of languages in the Content Editor to follow the order of language items under /sitecore/system/Languages using the setting ContentEditor.SortLanguages.  However, this has no impact on the order of languages from Database.GetLanguages(). Is there a way to apply this functionality to a front-end component, so that for example a language selector widget follows the language order of /sitecore/system/languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LanguageComparer to apply this ordering:

```
var sortedLangauges = currentItem.Database.GetLanguages.OrderBy((x => x),new LanguageComparer(currentItem.Database));
```

This is what the ContextEditor.SortLangauges setting uses behind the scenes.